# OnNewIntent() is called multiple times on a push notificatin

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin.forms, push-notification

I have a Xamarin.Forms application that has an issue with Android. To trigger a certain action, I use push notifications through Firebase. Push notifications are handled in OnNewIntent() of MainActivity. For some reason, upon a push notification's arrival, OnNewIntent() is called multiple times, which causes a problem. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach a flag to the event, and check for it to prevent duplicates from activating. You may also want to store the notification content and properties locally to compare new events.

A flag could be a timestamp, uniqueID, or related to the content itself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please give me an example or explanation on the flag attached to the event? We should take into account that there may be different notifications.

Comment: This tag you need to define with your requirements, such as what to do when you receive  "1" and what to do when you receive  "2".

Comment: @Leo Zhu - MSFT This is a good point. But there can be a situation when e.g. "1" comes from different devices, so they are not duplicates. I need to block only duplicated messages.

Comment: You would then create a hashmap, perhaps an md5 of the payload and use that as a unique ID